# How to create grid border in python?

Tags: python, colors, grid, cell

[image]

I am beginner in Python. I want to create grid with borders and fill color in specific cell. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

you could use Matplotlib, which is quite popular and well documented. A quick workaround would be to draw the data as an image and then add a rectangle for every cell.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plotCellGrid(data, ax=None, **kwargs):
  for x in range(data.shape[1]):
    for y in range(data.shape[0]):
      rect = plt.Rectangle((x-.5, y-.5), 1,1, fill=False, **kwargs)
      plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
 
   
img = np.random.rand(4,10)


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Reds')
plotCellGrid(img, color="black", linewidth=3)
plt.axis(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank You for that! Again, how to add color as specified in the image?